# adding float as values to a request array in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am adding this (float) str_replace(',', '', $orders['grandtotal']) to my store function but I am having issue, **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')'**

here's my store function look like

```
 $orders = Orders::create($request->only(
        'user_id',
        'status_id',
        'currency_id',
        'company_id',
        'purchase_no',
        'notes',
        'delivery_date',
        'grandtotal' =>(float) str_replace(',', '', $orders['grandtotal']),
        'publish'
    ));
```

[image: issues]

thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
 $data = $request->only(
    'user_id',
    'status_id',
    'currency_id',
    'company_id',
    'purchase_no',
    'notes',
    'delivery_date',
    'publish'
);
$data['grandtotal'] = (float) str_replace(',', '', $request->grandtotal);
$orders = Orders::create($data);
```